# Source for Yirmeyahu and Plato Meeting

Tags: sources-mekorot, navi-prophets, greek

I recently heard in a shiur that Plato and Yirmeyahu had met each other.
MY question is: What is the earliest source for this and where else can this story be found even if only quoting the original source (for example in the works of Rishonim, Achronim etc)

Comment: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/07/yirmeyahu-and-plato-in-egypt.html

Comment: @Harel13 your answer answers my question, but it is a different question than the one asked. So not sure if the question should be closed.

Comment: If it answers, that's great. The main point is whether your question has already been answered, not whether it has already been asked. Duplicate questions that don't have answers don't get closed.

Answer (score 2):

[Shalsheles HaKabbalah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&pgnum=247) quotes [R' Netanel ibn Kaspi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathanael_ben_Nehemiah_Caspi), who quotes Plato:

> אמר אפלטון אני הייתי עם ירמיהו במצרים ובתחילה הייתי לועג עליו ועל
> דבריו ולבסוף כאשר הרגלתי לדבר עמו ולדקדק במעשיו וראיתי כי דבריו דברי
> אלהים חיים אז אמרתי בלבי וקיימתי שהוא חכם ונביא.

The idea that Plato was a student of Yirmiyahu is cited by R' Yonasan Eibschutz in [Shem Olam](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6467&pgnum=83) from Abarbanel (I haven't checked Abarbanel for accuracy).

I've seen numerous *sefarim* (eg, [Galus U'Nechama](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20030&pgnum=52) from R' Shimshon Pincus, Lev Eliyahu from R' Elya Lopian) citing a story supposedly found in Toras HaOlah from the Rema, where Plato and Yirmiyahu met at the scene of the Churban, where Plato admonishes a weeping Yirmiyahu, and YIrmiyahu challenged Plato to a philosophical argument upon which Plato admitted Yirmiyahu's superior wisdom. I was unable to locate this in Toras HaOlah.

---

Edit:
I found this - the Rema's notes to Sefer Yuchasin.

[image]